# JoptionPane closing without doing anything

Tags: java, joptionpane

Am working on a project where i need to ask the user to enter a path to save the program using jOptionPane but my problem is if the user dont put anything in the text and click cancel or ok am getting an error...i tried to control it buy checking the string if is Empty() or equals to null

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Please consider revising your question as it is unclear which steps you have already taken, and the code which you have already tried in order to achieve you goal. Also, please consider reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for hints on how to improve your chances of the community being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a function for this JOptionPane, case you need back again, and don't forget to catch the errors with methods like NullPointerException.

```
public void optionPane(){
     String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("your text...");

      try{
      if((m == null) || (m.equals(""))){
           optionPane();
         }
      }catch(NullPointerException e){
          optionPane();
      }
  }
```